# Zope sendmail check if email was sent

Tags: sendmail, zope

Is there any way in which, by using zope.sendmail with DirectMailDelivery, after executing send() action, to retrieve a response or a status to see whether the email was sent or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, send() will return the messageid. Since the delivery is tied to the commit of the transaction (through a data manager) you can not check if it was sent or not. In case of a delivery problem you may see an exception from the transaction handler or data manager itself.